# Track specific products purchase with Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, triggers, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm having an issue with Google Tag Manager and Wordpress/WooCommerce
(I can't access to the backend).

I need to track when a specific type of product is purchased, the Sample of the main products (most of the products have their Sample).

The Sample can be purchased with other products or on its own.

I found a common element in the source code that is shown every time a Sample is purchased (see below). The element **colour-card-a5** appears when the sample is bought on the checkout page in two different areas:

Area #1

```
dataLayer.push({
  "pagePostType":"page",
  "pagePostType2":"single-page",
  "pagePostAuthor":"root",
  "ecommerce":{
    "currencyCode":"EUR",
    "purchase":{
      "actionField":{
        "id":"22481",
        "affiliation":"",
        "revenue":"1.70",
        "tax":"0",
        "shipping":"0.00",
        "coupon":""
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "id":13487,
          "name":"Genert",
          "sku":"AQA021",
          "category":"Contemporary",
          "price":1.7,
          "currency":"EUR",
          "stocklevel":null,
          "quantity":1,
          "variant":"colour-card-a5,interior-design"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "event":"gtm4wp.orderCompletedEEC"
});//]]>
```

Area #2

```
<td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/product/genert/?attribute_pa_size=colour-card-a5&attribute_pa_finish=interior-design">
      Genert - Colour Card (A5), Interior Design
    </a> 
    <strong class="product-quantity">&times; 1</strong> 
</td>
```

As the checkout page is example.com/checkout/order-received, I implemented this a Trigger:
**Trigger type:** *Element Visibility*

**Method:** *CSS Selector*

**Element Selector:** *colour-card-a5*

**When to fire this trigger:** *Once per page*

**Minimum Percent Visible:** *1*

**This trigger fires on:** *Some Visibility Events*

**Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true:**
*Page URL | contains | order received*

But once I buy the Sample, the tag it's not fired.
I'm sure I'm missing something but can't realise what.

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector provided (`colour-card-a5`) does not match any elements in your provided HTML. You should use `a[href*="colour-card-a5"]`, which will select any anchor, which has a href attribute, that contains colour-card-a5 string in it.

You should also check, if the element is present in the DOM during page load, or it is added later by a script. In this latter case, you should enable DOM inspection in the trigger setting, to allow triggering for any added elements.